# Angular/HTML - How to keep the same image proportions in an ngx gallery while zooming out in the browser?

Tags: html, css, angular, image, image-gallery

I'm making something in Angular and I was using the ngx gallery to make a gallery of images. I have an HTML app component that I use in a main HTML component. I have an issue of size when I zoom out on the browser.

This is what the gallery looks like before the zoom:

[image]

And this is what it looks like when zooming out (the images on the left look cut out, rather than squeezed):

[image]

Angular code (configuration of the ngx gallery in the app component)

```
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {  
 @Input() Images:Array<any> = [];   @Input() height:number =600;  
 galleryOptions: NgxGalleryOptions[];   galleryImages:
 NgxGalleryImage[] =[];
 
   constructor() {
 
    }
 
   ngOnInit(): void {
 
     this.galleryOptions = [
       {
 
         thumbnailsColumns: 6,
         imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Zoom,
         width: '80%',
         height:this.height.toString() + "px",
         lazyLoading:true,
         imageInfinityMove:true,
         imageSize:NgxGalleryImageSize.Cover,
         thumbnailsPercent: 20,
         thumbnailsMargin: 20,
         previewCloseOnClick:true,
         previewCloseOnEsc:true,
         preview: true,
         previewZoom:true ,
         previewAutoPlayPauseOnHover :true,
         previewInfinityMove:true,
         arrowPrevIcon : "fa fa-arrow-circle-left ",
         arrowNextIcon : "fa fa-arrow-circle-right "
 
       },
         // max-width 1200
         {
           breakpoint: 1200,
           width: '100%',
           imagePercent: 80,
           height:"250px",
           imageSize:NgxGalleryImageSize.Contain,
           thumbnailsPercent: 20,
           thumbnailsMargin: 20,
           thumbnailMargin: 20,
           thumbnails:false,
           preview: false,
         },
       // max-width 800
       {
         breakpoint: 800,
         width: '100%',
         imagePercent: 80,
         height:(this.height/2).toString()+"px",
         imageSize:NgxGalleryImageSize.Contain,
         thumbnailsPercent: 20,
         thumbnailsMargin: 20,
         thumbnailMargin: 20,
         thumbnails:false,
         preview: false,
       },
       // max-width 400
       {
         breakpoint: 400,
         height:(this.height/3).toString()+"px",
         imageSize:NgxGalleryImageSize.Contain,
         preview: false,
         thumbnails:false,
       }
     ];
 
   }
 
   ngOnChanges(){
     this.galleryImages= [];
     this.fillGallery(this.Images)
 
   }
 
 fillGallery( ArrayOfPhotos:Array<any>){
    for(let i = 0 ; i<ArrayOfPhotos.length;i++){
     this.galleryImages[i] =
       {
         small: ArrayOfPhotos[i].URL,
         medium: ArrayOfPhotos[i].URL,
         big: ArrayOfPhotos[i].URL
       };   }
 }
```

HTML code (of gallery)

```
 <ngx-gallery #gallery  [options]="galleryOptions"
 [images]="galleryImages" class="ngx-gallery img-fluid"></ngx-gallery>
```

HTML code (main file, where the app component is called)

```
<div *ngIf="!thingExists" class="content animated pulse ">
  <div class="container-fluid px-4 mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 ">
        <div class="text-center">
          <app-carousel [Images]="ImageCarousel" [height]="500" class="m-1"></app-carousel>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
          <div class="text-center">
            <app-other-thing></app-other-thing>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is, how can I fix this so the images don't change proportions when zooming out? But rather keep the same proportions (sort of like this [ngx gallery demo](https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/), if you zoom out they stay the same proportion).

Comment: replacement % with vh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, I solved this already by changing (in the Angular code section) `height` in px (which is 600) to `height` in vh (I used 60vh). Worked like a charm.